# Should I change size of all figures when changing the number of columns?

Tags: floats, two-column, width

I usually use a figure like

```
\begin{figure}[!t}
\subfigure[subcap1]{
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{filename.eps}
    \label{lab1}
}\\\subfigure[subcap2]{
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{filename.eps}
    \label{lab2}
}\\\subfigure[subcap3]{
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{filename.eps}
    \label{lab3}
}\caption{cap}
\end{figure}
```

However, when I change the paper type from 2 columns to 1 column, the figures become too large. Is there any method like the following?

- When I use 2 column papers, width is .9\linewidth.
- When I use 1 column paper, width is .4\linewidth?

My output is: 
[image]

Comment: Which package are you using -- `subfigure` or `subfig`? Please advise.

Comment: I am using \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} and \usepackage{subfigure}. Which one is better? I am willing to change if the subfig is better.

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete. use `subfig`.

Comment: @zarko Okay, I will study subfig, (ps, how to use black box in comments?)

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of your outputs under `twocolumn` and non-`twocolumn` mode? The reason why I'm asking is that `\linewidth` should suffice.

Comment: @Werner I edited.

Comment: @Danny_Kim: How about providing two examples of your code as well?

Comment: @Werner I just change between \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} and \documentclass[onecolumn,draftcls,12pt]{IEEEtran}. The rest codes are the same. But the linewidth is different between them (one column and two column). So, the result is like the above. :(

Comment: your question is not at all clear. If you want the figures to be as wide as your text block use `\linewidth` (or `.9\linewidth` if you want) but then naturally they are twice as wide if you make the text lines twice as wide. If you do not want the figure width to change in that way set it to a fixed width such as `width=4cm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can condition on the dimension using the class-provided `\ifCLASSOPTIONonecolumn`:

```
\includegraphics
  [width = \ifCLASSOPTIONonecolumn .4\linewidth\else.9\linewidth\fi]
  {example-image}
```

Using the `onecolumn` option sets `\CLASSOPTIONonecolumntrue`, otherwise it is `\CLASSOPTIONonecolumnfalse`. There is a `twocolumn` complement, but they are mutually exclusive so you can use one.

Answer (score 2):

package `subfigure` is obsolete. its supersede is `subfig`. syntay at using it is:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\subfloat[subcap1]{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{filename}
    \label{lab1}}\\
\subfloat[subcap2]{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{filename}
    \label{lab1}}\\
\subfloat[subcap2]{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{filename}
    \label{lab1}}
\caption{cap}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

even better is `subcaption` but it syntax is more different:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{0.9\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{filename}
    \caption{subcap1}
    \label{lab1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.9\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{filename}
    \caption{subcap3}
    \label{lab2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.9\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{filename}
    \caption{subcap3}
    \label{lab3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{cap}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

in both cases width of figures will adopt to width of columns.